# Authorization to run a Google Script for public with a protected worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to publish a Google Sheet running with a script, so that when you click on "Submit", the data is sent to another PROTECTED Google Sheet.

I have tried to run the cript with an account that doesn't have access to the PROTECTED Google Sheet, but it doens't work.

Do you know if there's any function that could be use, in order to let people submit, even if they do not have access of the "output" sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refer to this link for the documentation of Class Protection API that you can use to achieve your target:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection